# How do I cast __NSCFDictionary to 'NSArray in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, casting, converters

I have recently been updating a library to swift 3.0 as a relatively new swift dev. I get a error where I cannot cast __NSCFDictionary to a NSArray format. How could I convert __NSCFDictionary to NSArray format in swift with a example please?

This is the current function I am converting

```
 method(name: "login", params: NSArray(arrayLiteral: params)) //fails casting here
        guard let e = error , (e.isValid == true) else {

            if let user = params["user"] as? AnyObject {
                if let email = user["email"] {
                    self.userData.set(email, forKey: DDP_EMAIL)
                }
                if let username = user["username"] {
                    self.userData.set(username, forKey: DDP_USERNAME)
                }
            }

            if let data = result as? NSDictionary,
                let id = data["id"] as? String,
                let token = data["token"] as? String,
                let tokenExpires = data["tokenExpires"] as? NSDictionary {
                    let expiration = dateFromTimestamp(containedIn: tokenExpires)
                    self.userData.set(id, forKey: DDP_ID)
                    self.userData.set(token, forKey: DDP_TOKEN)
                    self.userData.set(expiration, forKey: DDP_TOKEN_EXPIRES)
            }

            self.userMainQueue.addOperation() {

                if let c = callback { c(result, error) }
                self.userData.set(true, forKey: DDP_LOGGED_IN)

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: DDP_USER_DID_LOGIN), object: nil)

                if let _ = self.delegate {
                    self.delegate!.ddpUserDidLogin(user: self.user()!)
                }

            }

            return
        }

        log.debug("Login error: \(e)")
        if let c = callback { c(result, error) }
    }
```

Comment: Arrays and dictionaries are conceptually different and used for different purposes.  Why are you trying to convert from one to the other?  What do you need to accomplish?

Comment: I an converting a library that somebody else made so my understanding is limited, but for some reason a function passes a __NSCFDictionary that needs to be converted to NSArray format to be used in json format

Comment: You will need to first understand the code that you are converting. This is probably a good way to become a much better Swift dev; study what you have. The answer to your question as given is "you don't; that's not a thing." But I think with some exploration you will be able to find the better question. At the very least, devise a small piece of code that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve so we can see what you mean.

Comment: Please post your code.  As this question stands now it's nigh impossible to answer.

Comment: Why is `NSArray(arrayLiteral:` here at all? `params` is a dictionary according to your error. The callback seems to expect it to be a dictionary. Why convert it to an array?

Comment: As always, in Swift avoid Foundation collection types as much as possible.